# Public Function vs Public Sub

Tags: vb.net, oop

I've written a simple program to calculate the first 5 numbers in a linear sequence. The program was originally sequential involving a sub in Main() to perform the calculation. However, as a relative beginner to coding, I am trying to develop my understanding of object orientated programming so, as a challenge, I decided to re-write the program accordingly. As you will see from the code below, I've hit a little conundrum which, I hope, some of you may be able to help me out with.

By using a public sub I can perform the required task by creating a new instance of the class in Main() and calling GetSequence … no problems. However, I don't like the idea of using a Console.Write line within a Class. Correct me if I am wrong, but won't this negate the true purpose of creating a class since it removes its dynamic functionality?

So, as an alternative, I've tried to perform the same calculation within a public function, but unfortunately the return value is not recognized within the for loop. I'm sure there is a way around this…something glaringly obvious I've missed, but I just can't see it.

Any help with this, as always, most appreciated.

```
    Public Class Sequence
    Public Property a As Integer
    Public Property b As Integer

    'Using Public Sub does the job, but it means using a 
    'Console.Write within the Sequence class, which I'm
    'not too happy about.

    Public Sub GetSequence()

    For n = 1 To 5
        Console.Write("{0}, ", a * n + b)
    Next
    End Sub

    'I'd prefer to use a Public Function, but how do I 
    'return the value of the function through each iteration
    'of the 'for' loop?

    Public Function GetSequence(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)

        For n = 0 To 5
            Return a * n + b
        Next
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = b
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to use a yield statement - take a look at this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/yield-statement

The example code given is as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    For Each number In Power(2, 8)
        Console.Write(number & " ")
    Next
    ' Output: 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Private Iterator Function Power(
ByVal base As Integer, ByVal highExponent As Integer) _
As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Integer)

    Dim result = 1

    For counter = 1 To highExponent
        result = result * base
        Yield result
    Next
End Function
```

Note that the For Each loop is calling the function, which is defined as an Iterator, which makes it possible to Yield the value back to the For Each for every generated result.

Comment: Thanks for your help jlmt. The Yield statement is a concept I haven't come across before, so thanks for introducing to me. I'll have a look into it and have a play around. As I mentioned, I am a relative beginner, so building on existing is very important to me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

For this small example, you can just create a string and append to it repeatedly (also making sure to declare the function’s return type – enable `Option Strict` project-wide):

```
Public Function GetSequence(a As Integer, b As Integer) As String
    Dim result As String = ""

    For n = 0 To 5
        result &= (a * n + b) & ", "
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

LINQ is nicer, but maybe more advanced than you want to get into right now.

```
Public Function GetSequence(a As Integer, b As Integer) As String
    Return String.Join(
        ", ",
        From n In Enumerable.Range(0, 6) Select (a * n + b).ToString()
    )
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ryan. As mentioned in the previous comment, new concepts to problem solving are very important to me as a beginner. I haven't come across the  'Option Strict' procedure you mentioned, but that's what learning is about. I'll look into it and thanks again Ryan, most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a "sequence" to be an entity, and you want to be able to enumerate this entity's values from outside.

An idiomatic way of doing that would be implementing the `IEnumerable` interface:

```vb
Public Class Sequence
    Implements IEnumerable(Of Integer)

    Public ReadOnly Property a As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property b As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
        Me.a = a
        Me.b = b
    End Sub


    Public Iterator Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of Integer) Implements IEnumerable(Of Integer).GetEnumerator
        For n = 0 To 5
            Yield a * n + b
        Next
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return Me.GetEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class
```

```vb
Dim s As New Sequence(1, 3)

For Each i In s
    Console.WriteLine(i)
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help GSerg. Each of the three solutions  I have seen so far have introduced me to entirely new procedures and tools within the .NET library. As I mentioned, I am a beginner, less than 3 months coding experience, so all of the solutions presented here will keep me busy for a couple of weeks at least. Again, thank you so much for helping my learning journey - most appreciated.